# Create new view controller upon UICollectionViewCell clicked

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I currently have a `UICollectionView` table with cells, I am trying to allow each cell that is created to have their own unique view controller. For example, when the `UICollectionViewCell` is tapped, the view controller shows for that specific cell. I know that I can create one viewcontroller and perform a segue to only that one view controller. That only covers one cell... If the user creates 25 cells... how do I make a view controller for each cell without making a segue? The code below is to create a cell.

```
// MARK: Create collection View cell with title, image, and rounded border

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ChatCell
    let object = objects[indexPath.row]

    cell.chatLabel.text = object.title ?? ""
    cell.chatImage.image = object.image
    if let chatImagePath = object.imagePath {
        if let imageURL = URL(string: chatImagePath) {
        cell.chatImage.sd_setImage(with: imageURL)
        }
    }
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objects.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let itemWidth = photoCollectionView.bounds.width
    let itemHeight = photoCollectionView.bounds.height / 2
    return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
}
```

Comment: But do you _really_ have 25 completely different designs for these destination view controllers? Or are they the same fundamental type of view controller, just showing different data?

Comment: @Rob I want a view controller to be created for that cell... I cant have all the cells refer to the same view controller

Comment: @Rob yes they all have the same layout but I want to post different data on each

Comment: @Rob So I can use the segue to a view controller but the prepare(for:sender:) data that I put,  will create the "specific data" for that view controller? Am I understanding that correctly

Comment: Basically, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments under your question, you clarified that you really only have one basic type of view controller that you're transitioning to, but you want to make sure that you supply the correct information to it on the basis of which cell of the collection view you tapped on.

There are two basic approaches:

1. Easiest, in IB, create a segue from the collection view cell to the next scene in the storyboard, and then implement [`prepare(for:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare) in the originating scene to pass whatever you need to that next scene.

   For example, you might have a `prepare(for:sender:)` that does something like:

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first, let destination = segue.destination as? DetailsViewController {
           destination.object = objects[indexPath.item]
       }
   }
   ```

   Now, this makes a ton of assumptions (e.g. that my collection view has an array, `objects`, that my destination view controller is a `DetailsViewController`, that it has some `object` property, etc.), but hopefully it illustrates the basic idea.
2. You said you didn't want to use a segue. I'm not sure why, but, if you really don't want segue, then just use implement [`collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview) and initiate the transition programmatically, however you want.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want to do... I am trying to create a segue from clicking the cell to show a tableviewcontroller for that specific cell...

Comment: Would you like to see my github project?

Comment: Sure, if it's not too hairy. If there's a ton of unrelated code, you might want to reduce it to a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do I need to use a segue identifier...?

Comment: ok makes sense... I want a nav bar to be in this view controller... shouldn't I segue to the navigation view controller ?

Comment: @KimRiegel - I'd suggest that we stop exchanging comments here, and [move it to chat if you have future questions](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149270/discussion-between-rob-and-kim-riegel). I've removed my portion of the comments here, as they're captured in chat, now.